# js variable only can be access inside loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var valueku = url;
for (var e = 0; e < cotLength; e++) {
    if (dataprofil[e + 1].one == dataprofil[e].one) {
        total = parseInt(dataprofil[e + 1].three) + parseInt(dataprofil[e].three);
        total2 = parseInt(dataprofil[e].four);
        sum = total * total2;
        dataprofil[e].three = total;
        dataprofil.splice(e + 1, 1);
    }
    valueku = valueku.concat(dataprofil[e].one, ":", dataprofil[e].two, "=", sum, "&");
    alert("inside= " + valueku); //inside loop is 1,2,3,4,5
}
alert("outside= " + valueku); //outside loop should be the last value of valueku --> 12345
```

the question is why i only can see alert message in inside loop but no alert message outside loop? outside loop should be the last value of variable valueku.

Comment: Is `alert("outside= "+valueku);` executed? Do you see the "outside=" message?

Comment: Does valueku always have valid value? Can u check console for error messages? The reason code never gets to outside could be it throws exception in one of the loops

Comment: Ran your code fine. Have you F12'd into devtools to check for an error? http://jsfiddle.net/wkqnexfo/

Comment: yeah, if `cotLength - 1` is longer than `dataprofil.length` you'll see an error and the code won't complete. Can you show us what's in `cotLength` and `dataprofil`?

Comment: @Igor: alert("outside= "+valueku); is not executed at all, even theres no blank message

Answer (score 0):

Possible you get javascript error on the last iteration,
which prevents further program executing:

```
if (dataprofil[e + 1].one
```

Do you really have that `e+1`st value? if `cotLength`is the length of `dataprofil`, the `dataprofil[e + 1]` will be undefined

Comment: yes i guess it search for value e+1.. and for the last array, of course i dont have last value to compared. so how to alert the last valueku outside the loop? i really need to use logic e+1 to compare the same value with the next value

Comment: Just reduce the iteration: for (var e = 0; e < cotLength-1; e++)   Last value will be alerted in outside as soon as there will be no JS errors on the way

Comment: if i put  for (var e = 0; e < cotLength-1; e++)  it work, it alerted outside the loop but the last array value not show...

Comment: i have resolved it by adding 1 data with any string :D. thanks ma1ao